# Can the comments get a text editor too?

Tags: feature-request

when I make a comment all my sentences end up jammed together and I look like I have run-off-at-the-mouth-itis.  The text editor for questions is sophisticated and easy to use...could it be available for comments too?
What I'm looking for is new line feed, indent...easy features

Answer (score 4):

This won't be accepted, it's already been discussed upstream on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comments should be advisory, not embellishments.